# Php user profile - What should i do?

Tags: php

I made login and registration system. It works fine but the main problem is user profile page. I made a profile.php page but it works for each session. I need to make like this:

```
domain.com/profile/username
```

I mean when i click someone's username, i want it navigate me to the username's profile page. Bytheway i couldn't make `$id = $_GET['username']` i can't get how it works. I'm working with `$_POST` to login.

How can i make profile page for each user?

Thank you.

Comment: Change the profile code to pull the username from the GET request and not the SESSION. Avoid `int` and use username for lookup. (presuming you make sure not to allow duplicate usernames).

Comment: Okay i'll try to use GET request to display user. Thanks Lawrence.

Comment: Usernames are unique. I worked on it :)

Comment: If you want `example.com/profile/username` and not `example.com/profile?id=username` you need to use rewrites. - [mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and “pretty links” explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: I exactly want to do that. Rewrite is the key :)

Answer (score 0):

In profile.php make a function that gets the URI example:
Profile?id=1

$user = $_GET[‘id'];
 //make the database statement which gets all the info about $user and return this on the page

Comment: Everytime you enter /profile.php?id= the id you want it gets the user its profile picture or whatever you like

Comment: I'll brb when i try this. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Is it possible to make profile/username with Get method ?

Comment: No because the GET is meant to GET a value that has been set in the URI example of what you can do: profile/username?username= the user name WHICH means that you now can GET the username

Comment: I think that i want to use " / " instead of " ? " in the url. Because it seems easier to type for the users :)

Comment: That is possible just hide the php ?username in your .htaccess BUT this doesnt mean that you get rid of the ? In your php you will need to use this but the user wont see it because the htaccess takes care of this